# Forward http://example.org/sitemap.xml to https://example.org/sitemap.xml using .htaccess file

Tags: xml, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

The question I am asking is pretty much in the title.

how do I forward http://example.org/sitemap.xml to https://example.org/sitemap.xml using the .htaccess file?

I need to do this as the WordPress plugin I am using does not index pages that are SSL encrypted, whereas if the sitemap itself is also in https, the pages are included, so how do I use .htaccess to redirect people, I have this in my .htaccess but it does not seem to work

```
# BEGIN Custom Edits

#//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://example.org/sitemap.xml https://example.org/sitemap.xml

# END Custom Edits
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following set of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(sitemap\.xml)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your Redirect line is that the first URL should be a path, not a full URL. What you want is more like:

```
Redirect permanent /sitemap.xml https://example.org/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Thank you, much help, but this does not work, because that causes a redirect loop. this answer would work in some cases though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you’re right: in the .htaccess file the Redirect directive will apply to both HTTP and HTTPS. In order to use a Redirect it would need to be in the virtual host section of the Apache configuration.

mod_rewrite is a bit heavyweight for this purpose, but that’s what you’re going to have to use, as in the other answer.